# Ruby - MySQL server has gone away (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

This is a duplicate question. The answers related with this question is not helping me anyway. Please help me out to get rid of this problem.

**MySQL Query:**

```
insert_query = %{INSERT INTO my_table (`my_column`) VALUES("#{my_value}");}.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => 'localhost', :username => "#{ENV['MYSQLUSERNAME']}", :password => "#{ENV['MYSQLPASSWORD']}")
client.query("USE `my_database`;")
client.query(insert_query)
```

While inserting the value into my_column, i get an error *"`query': MySQL server has gone away" (Mysql2::Error)*. my_column has MEDIUMTEXT data type and it will store encoded string value in it. If the encoded(using Base64.encode64 in Ruby) string character count is more(more than 1,00,000 or 1,00,00,000) then i am facing an error. But If the encoded string length is less, then it works well. I have tried setting up wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet. But not helping me in anyway!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve that, you should increase the maximal packet size limit “max_allowed_packet” in `/etc/my.cnf` file (if file doesn't exist, you can create it).

you can set: `max_allowed_packet = 128M`

and then restart mysql

Comment: did you try to increase `connect_timeout` ?

Comment: Yes. But that too did not work. Do i need to set up those variables into /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf ?

Comment: Set: `max_allowed_packet = 128M` in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** worked for me. Thanks!